# Need two indexes on a HABTM join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, indexing

A simple `has_and_belongs_to_many` association:

```
Person has_and_belongs_to_many :products
Product has_and_belongs_to_many :persons
```

Are **both** of the following indexes helpful for optimal performance?

```
add_index :person_products, [:person_id, :product_id]
add_index :person_products, [:product_id, :person_id]
```

Answer (score 56):

Close - you most likely want the following:

```
add_index :person_products, [:person_id, :product_id], :unique => true
add_index :person_products, :product_id
```

The `:unique => true` is not strictly required and it depends whether or not it makes sense to have a person associated with a product multiple times.  I would say if you're not sure, you probably *do* want the `:unique` flag.

The reason for the index structure is that all modern databases can execute queries on both person_id and product_id using the first index *regardless of the order specified in a query*.  E.g.

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE person_id = 1 AND product_id = 2
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE product_id = 2 AND person_id = 1
```

are treated as the same and the database is smart enough to use the first index.

Likewise, queries using only `person_id` can also be run using the first index.  Multi-column b-tree indexes can use fewer columns than they have provided they are specified from the left of the original declaration.

For queries using only `product_id`, this cannot be executed against the first index (since that index is defined with person_id in the leftmost position).  Hence you need a separate index to enable lookups on that field alone.

The multi-column b-tree index property also extends to indexes with higher numbers of columns.  If you had an index on `(person_id, product_id, favorite_color, shirt_size)`, you could use that index to run queries using `person_id`, `(person_id, product_id)`, etc, so long as the order matches the definition.

Answer (score 4):

Yes they are helpful. But do you really need them? It all depends on what you're gonna do with it.
Index on `(person_id,product_id)` will allow you to quickly find products belonging to person but will not help finding persons that own certain product. It will also enforce UNIQUE so you probably should use it.
separate indexes on `(person_id)` and `(product_id)` will allow you to find both products belonging to person and persons that own certain product.
Indices on `(person_id,product_id)` and `(product_id,person_id)` will work for both cases too and will be faster but will take more space and there will take a little bit (very little) more when inserting/updating rows. The time and space overhead is almost always worth it unless you have a base where you write more often than read.
Personally I've seen Index Only Scans in 9.2 benefit greatly from two indexes on both columns.
So you the real choice is between:

`unique index on (col 2, col 1), unique index on (col 1, col 2)`

and

`unique Index on (col 1, col 2), index on (col 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You just need one, unless you are doing `unique`

```
add_index :person_products, :person_id
add_index :person_products, :product_id
```

Or for an index on both columns

```
add_index :person_products, [:person_id, :product_id]
```

This will help performance when querying on those columns on the database.  It will depend on your query if it includes both columns or just one.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index

Comment: My understanding is, if the query goes by `product_id` and then `person_id`, it will not use the index on both columns that you have above.